# Is this an appropriate forum for questions relating to web design?

Tags: support

I do a lot of web design, and frequently have trouble with CSS3 animation compatibility across browsers. Is this the appropriate SE site to ask questions relating to those kinds of problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Designing for the web? Yes. Implementing designs for the web? No. Implementation questions are off topic, and generally are on topic for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

By "implementation questions" I mean pretty much anything pertaining directly to how you write the code. If your code isn't right in that it's not producing the results you expect, ask or search Stack Overflow for HTML/CSS/Javascript/etc issues. If the *concept* or *completed design* aren't right in that they're not achieving some goal with *users* (high bounce rate, your controls are confusing, you're not sure how to present X) that's on topic here.

From your question, it sounds like you want Stack Overflow for that.

Comment: Which is just as well, as it gives you a chance to pick up some Stack Overflow rep anyway.